# How to fix this verterx which sticking out

Tags: vertices, weight-painting

I have my crharacter which is riged and waight panted but pinky finger have one verterx sticking out even its 100% painted in red

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other bone has also influence on that vertex. Turn on the "Vertex selection masking", then select that vertex, and remove it from all vertex groups, then reassign to the pinky or repaint it with the weight brush.[image]

Comment: Tnx mean you saved my day