# How do I remove weight paint from specific linked mesh?

Tags: weight-painting

I have a model made of entirely different objects joined together (none of them are linked) and made a rig for it. I put automatic weights when I parented the model to the rig, but when I checked the weight paint, there were a few bones that had influence over a mesh that I didn't really want.

I could always do it manually and just remove the weight paint myself but I have a fear of messing up everything instead after accidentally removing paint that wasn't supposed to be removed.

So is there a way to remove all weight paint from one specific linked mesh? Most of the automatic weights on the model have pretty much done what I wanted them to do.

Comment: Have you tried [separating](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object) the mesh, then removing the weight paint from it and re-joining it again?

Comment: Select the linked vertices with CTRL+L then remove them from all vertex groups. Here is a picture where can you find it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137137/how-to-fix-this-verterx-which-sticking-out/137138#137138